Internet jail with Squid for Windows 7
I'm trying to set up an internet jail for a VM with Windows 7 using Squid 5.9 (OpenSSL 3.0.2).
The guest is firewalled to the gills, the Squid port being the only possible link with the outside, everything else being ignored. Squid is configured with a redirector that nixes anything that isn't in a VERY small whitelist, otherwise replies OK. To police HTTPS connections too, I've configured Squid to bump all connections. A self-signed "snake-oil.evil" CA was created and the certificate was imported in both the system and Firefox trusted CA certificates store. Squid is configured as an explicit proxy for both HTTP and HTTPS for both Firefox and IE.
Now the issue: In Firefox everything seems OK, but in the same VM, same page, Internet Explorer simply says "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Running the troubleshooting wizard provides no further insight. In the access and redirector logs I see that IE tries to access the site 3 times. Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks.
Squid has in the config:
http_port 3188 ssl-bump \
   cert=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/snake-oil-ca.pem \
   generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB

acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3
#ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all

Commenting/uncommenting peek on step1 doesn't seem to have an effect.
Some data about the certificate (sensitive values have been removed)
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            xx:xx:...
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = CA, ST = ON, O = SnakeOil, CN = snake-oil.evil
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 1 01:00:00 2024 GMT
            Not After : Dec 1 01:00:00 2044 GMT
        Subject: C = CA, ST = ON, O = SnakeOil, CN = snake-oil.evil
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                   xx:xx...
                   ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                xx:xx:..
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:xx:xx:...
                DirName:/C=CA/ST=ON/O=SnakeOil/CN=snake-oil.evil
                serial:xx:xx:...
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        xx:xx:...

Access log for IE:
1734150297.708    128 192.168.56.107 NONE_NONE/200 0 CONNECT permitted.page:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
1734150297.754     44 192.168.56.107 NONE_NONE/200 0 CONNECT permitted.page:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
1734150297.797     41 192.168.56.107 NONE_NONE/200 0 CONNECT permitted.page:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
1734150297.838     39 192.168.56.107 NONE_NONE_ABORTED/200 0 CONNECT permitted.page:443 - HIER_NONE/- -

cache.log for IE:
2024/12/13 23:40:44.008 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x60889a3a17a8 checking slow rules
2024/12/13 23:40:44.008 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: Safe_ports = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: !Safe_ports = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#1 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: CONNECT = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: SSL_ports = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: !SSL_ports = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#2 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49162' NOT found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: localhost = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#3 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| RegexData.cc(44) match: checking 'permitted.page:443'
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: manager = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#4 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49162' NOT found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: localhost = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#5 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49162' found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: snakeoil = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#6 = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer=ALLOWED
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x60889a3a17a8 checking slow rules
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49162' found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: all = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (ssl_bump rule) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (ssl_bump rules) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.009 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer=ALLOWED
2024/12/13 23:40:44.010 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x7fffc6abe7c0 checking fast ACLs
2024/12/13 23:40:44.010 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log line) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.010 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.010 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x7fffc6abe7c0 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x60889a3a17a8 checking slow rules
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: Safe_ports = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: !Safe_ports = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#1 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: CONNECT = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: SSL_ports = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: !SSL_ports = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#2 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49163' NOT found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: localhost = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#3 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| RegexData.cc(44) match: checking 'permitted.page:443'
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: manager = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#4 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49163' NOT found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: localhost = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#5 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49163' found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: snakeoil = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#6 = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.011 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer=ALLOWED
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x60889a3a17a8 checking slow rules
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49163' found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: all = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (ssl_bump rule) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (ssl_bump rules) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer=ALLOWED
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x7fffc6abe7c0 checking fast ACLs
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log line) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.012 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x7fffc6abe7c0 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x60889a3a17a8 checking slow rules
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: Safe_ports = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: !Safe_ports = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#1 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: CONNECT = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: SSL_ports = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: !SSL_ports = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#2 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49164' NOT found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: localhost = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#3 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| RegexData.cc(44) match: checking 'permitted.page:443'
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: manager = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#4 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49164' NOT found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: localhost = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#5 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49164' found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: snakeoil = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#6 = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer=ALLOWED
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x60889a3a17a8 checking slow rules
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49164' found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: all = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (ssl_bump rule) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (ssl_bump rules) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.013 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer=ALLOWED
2024/12/13 23:40:44.015 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x7fffc6abe7c0 checking fast ACLs
2024/12/13 23:40:44.015 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log line) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.015 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.015 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x7fffc6abe7c0 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x60889a3a17a8 checking slow rules
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: Safe_ports = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: !Safe_ports = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#1 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: CONNECT = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: SSL_ports = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: !SSL_ports = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#2 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49165' NOT found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: localhost = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#3 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| RegexData.cc(44) match: checking 'permitted.page:443'
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: manager = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#4 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49165' NOT found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: localhost = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#5 = 0
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49165' found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: snakeoil = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access#6 = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: http_access = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.017 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer=ALLOWED
2024/12/13 23:40:44.018 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x60889a3a17a8 checking slow rules
2024/12/13 23:40:44.018 kid1| 28,3| Ip.cc(538) match: aclIpMatchIp: '192.168.56.107:49165' found
2024/12/13 23:40:44.018 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: all = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.018 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (ssl_bump rule) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.018 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (ssl_bump rules) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.018 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer ALLOWED for match
2024/12/13 23:40:44.018 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(163) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x60889a3a17a8 answer=ALLOWED
2024/12/13 23:40:44.019 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(70) preCheck: 0x7fffc6abe7a0 checking fast ACLs
2024/12/13 23:40:44.019 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: (access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log line) = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.019 kid1| 28,3| Acl.cc(151) matches: checked: access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log = 1
2024/12/13 23:40:44.019 kid1| 28,3| Checklist.cc(63) markFinished: 0x7fffc6abe7a0 answer ALLOWED for match


I would guess the good old Internet Explorer might not be able to handle the "Public Key Algorithm".
